# Синтаксис фильтра QFileDialog

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qfiledialog

Где можно посмотреть синтаксис фильтра для `QFileDialog`? В [документации](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#details) сказано только про то, что разделять разные фильтры можно с помощью `;;`. Как разделять разные экстеншны? Можно ли использовать разделитель при 1 экстеншене/фильтре?

Comment: По вашей же ссылке все написано

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте воспользоваться методом:

`setNameFilter(tr("Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"));`

Пример взят из официальной документации (по вашей ссылке он есть). В качестве строки вы можете передать все необходимые вам расширения. Например для текста:

`setNameFilter(tr("Text (*.txt *.doc *.docx)"));`